# Asynchrous replication in MariaDB Galera Cluster

Tags: mariadb, galera

Datacenter DC1 and Datacenter DC2 are 60 miles apart and Datacenter DC3 is 600 miles apart from DC1 and DC2.

I would like to have 3 node MariaDB Galera Custer,one node in each data center.

Data Center  MariaDB Galera Node
DC1 :        MDB01
DC2 :        MDB02
DC2 :        MDB03

Because of MariaDB Galera Cluster multi-master synchronous replication nature, transaction has to wait till it replicates to all the three nodes.There will be latency because of MDB03 node which is in datacenter DC3 which is 600 miles from the other two nodes.

Therefore I would like to have  two nodes MDB01 and MDB02 should be in synchronous replication mode and node MDB03 in asynchronous mode.

Is it possible to setup such configuration in MariaDB Galera Cluster?

Answer (score 0):

That configuration would lose most of the HA benefits.

Given that all 3 are fully in the cluster...  Let's say the 600 miles equates to 25ms.  That is small enough for the typical user not to notice.  And it means that you could `COMMIT` up to 40 transactions per second *per* connection.  Is that not good enough?

Comment: However out of my curiosity just want know is there way to configure one of the MariaDB Galera cluster node to be configured  for asynchronous mode. Here I am not interested in two node MariaDB Galera cluster and one asynchronous replication to another stand alone MariaDB instance.

Comment: The nodes in a single Galera cluster will be synchronous.  Another server (or cluster) can be connected to that cluster via asynchronous replication.  But doing so loses many of the Galera features.  I would build all nodes into a single Galera cluster and try it.  It _may_ be fast enough.